# How to calculate a distance between two cities using cartography?

Tags: google-maps, distance, euclidean-distance, cartography

I have latitude and longitude of two cities. Is there any free option to calculate the travel distance between these cities using cartography?

At the moment, I implemented the Haversine formula for computing the great-circle distance. Then I multiply the distance by the correction factor (e.g. 0.7 - measured empirically).

This approach gives a quick approximation. But how can I do the same thing using a real cartography?

Comment: you mean the distance e.g. by using roads to travel from a to b?

Answer (score 0):

You may e.g. use the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

Sample-Request(driving-distance from paris to rome)

[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=paris&destinations=rome&mode=driving`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=paris&destinations=rome&mode=driving)